# Dependency in SQL

Tags: sql-server, dependencies

In SQL, I've to delete a data from table `A` which is dependent on table `B`.
The data to be deleted should satisfy two conditions `WorkArea='123' and FileNo='45'`.

Table `B` has `WorkArea` but it does not contain data for `FileNo`.
And Table `A` contains the record satisfying both the conditions.

There isn't any reference key. For more clarity, adding a query here:

Select * from table A where WorkArea='123' and FileNo='45';

This will generate the resulting record. But as it is dependent on Table B, I cannot delete it directly. Also, to delete it from table B isn't possible because data in WorkArea is a whole and it contains many files and I have to delete a specific File.

So how can I delete data from table `A`?

[This is Table A with col1 and col2 as primary key.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IVET.png)

[This is Table B with col1 as a primary key.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSGWs.png)

Comment: table structure please...

Comment: Add some sample table data and structure.

Comment: Do you have any foreign key setup between those tables ? And like everyone before me said : table structure/data (examples) may be required to answer you

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Foreign Keys, the following sentence will work.

```
DELETE FROM [A] WHERE [WorkArea] = '123' AND [FileNo] = '45';
```

Then you can programmaticaly check if there are "orphans" on table `B` with the following request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [B].[WorkArea]
FROM [B]
LEFT JOIN [A]
ON [A].[WorkArea] = [B].[WorkArea]
WHERE [A].[WorkArea] IS NULL
```

To enhance this last part and produce a `DELETE` sentence from it, just store the result of this request into a temporary table then use it as a `WHERE` statement with the `IN` keyword.

Comment: Thank you @Hybris95 for your instant help!